# Why are my mods gone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mcpatcher

I used MCpatcher to run Misa's texture pack and all my mods except for TooManyItems were gone!

Why did this happen?

For the record, I saved them and I have reinstalled SinglePlayerCommands and will reinstall The Clay Soldiers mod.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what mods were present, but it is possible that the patcher wasn't compatible with them. See, though it is a patcher, if the files are modified too much, it can't tell where to insert code. This will cause it to overwrite those files.

Often, MCPatcher is updated to be compatible with *specific* mods, so those conflicts don't happen. However, this requires fine-tuning. It's probable that your mods weren't actually deleted, but were *partially* overwritten. This can either lead to a black-screen crash, or the mods simply appearing like they don't exist. The latter clearly happened in this case.

Though the patcher is great, I've found that patching it *before* I install other mods has never lead to conflicts, while patching it after sometimes has. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the mod you were trying to install overwrote the class files inside your jar that those mods used. Thus, removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that the mods just didn't show up in MCPatcher, or you started up Minecraft and saw that they weren't installed any more?  I noticed once or twice back when I used to use MCPatcher that sometimes it would just "forget" what mods I had installed, removing them from the list the next time I ran the program.  The mods themselves were still installed, and would show up properly in-game, but MCPatcher couldn't tell.

I've since switched to the MultiMC Launcher since I've started running a few different instances of Minecraft and I needed a way to manage that.